# How to publish Google Glass Card Layout using Android Developer Tools (ADT)?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm developing an immersive app on Glass using the GDK and Android Developer Tools (ADT) , but when I publish my code to Google Glass, i get the android header which takes up alot of real estate when viewing it on Glass. I don't want it.

[image: droidAtScreen-1.0.2 screenshot]

**How do I not include the top bars (dark background): battery, wireless, time when deployign to Glass?**

I just want the content that is inside the window (light grey area), if there is a setting somewhere in my code or ADT, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse and Android Studio automatically add a theme to the `<application>` element in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file when you create a new project, and this theme is not appropriate for Glass. Make sure that you remove the `android:theme` attribute from that element to get the default Glass look.

You can find more information [in the GDK documentation](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui/theme-widgets#applying_the_glass_theme).

Comment: I removed android:theme="@style/AppTheme" and it worked, thank you!